# Casting Primitive Values

Tags: overflow, underflow

Value: 1,921,222, is too large to be stored as a short, so numeric overflow occurs and it becomes 20,678.

Can anyone demonstrate the process of 1,921,222 becoming 20,678 ?
how to “wraps around” to the next lowest value and counts up from there to get 20,678
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In language C, the "short" type has 2 bytes. Every integer value is treated by the compiler as a 32-bit or 4-byte "int" type (this can vary depending on the compiler).

```
 short s = 1921222;
```

In this sentence you are losing 2 bytes of data:

```
                Information that remains in the variable (2 bytes)
                      ^         ^
 00000000 00011101 01010000 11000110   ->  total data (4 bytes, 32 bits)
    v        v
 Information discarded when you put this value in a short type.
```

In other words, you "crop" the data, leaving only the part that fits the specified type.

```
01010000 11000110
```

"01010000 11000110" is 20678.

This site can help you to understand better how this process works:
https://hexed.it/